# Flipping two coins; $X$ is how many times first coin is flipped until heads, $Y$ is how many times second coin is flipped until heads

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The first part of the question is to find the probability that the two coins take the same number of flips to land on heads, which I found to be $1/3$.The next part, which I'm stuck on, it to find the conditional probability mass function of $X$ given that both coins land on heads on the same number of flips. Any help?

Comment: Please explain how you found 1/3. The second result should follow.

Comment: i created a geometric series in which the probability that they land on the first try is (.5)^2, the second try (.5)^4..........5^(2n). The equation becomes (.5^)/(1-(.5^2)) which equals 1/3

Comment: Hence you know the probability p(n) that the two coins take the same number of flips to land on heads AND that this number X of flips is n. How to deduce the conditional distribution of X?

Answer (score 0):

The solution alluded to by Did in a comment:

$$
\textsf P(X=x\mid X=Y)=\frac{\textsf P(X=x\cap X=Y)}{\textsf P(X=Y)}=\frac{\left(\frac14\right)^x}{\frac13}=\frac3{4^x}\;.
$$